# How to code in Javascript to build digest password that takes Nonce+Timestamp+Password

Tags: javascript, passwords, digest

Password generating algorithm used is 
`Base64(SHA1($NONCE + $TIMESTAMP + SHA1($CLEARPASSWORD)))`

I need to develop code in Javascript to generate the digest password in a client application.

Comment: Please add some code to let us see what you tried

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will help you if you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) code. We can't make code for you.